# Is there a way in lein to run clojure tests from a jar file?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojure.test

I would like to build a jar file containing a suite of `clojure.test` tests, and then use `lein test` to run those tests. As far as I can tell, `:test-paths` only supports paths to test source, not test jars.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by manually creating a test runner.  Suppose you have a project `demo` and a testing ns `tst.demo.core` like so:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core clojure.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(deftest t1 (println "test t1"))
(deftest t2 (println "test t2"))
```

Under the `src/demo` directory, create a test driver `demo.tst` like so:

```
(ns demo.tst
  (:use clojure.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [tst.demo.core :as tdc] )
  (:gen-class))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defn pi []  (println 3.14))
(spyx (pi))
(spyx (#'pi))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (spyx (ns-interns 'tst.demo.core))
  (let [tst-vars (vals (ns-interns 'tst.demo.core))]
    (spyx tst-vars)
    (doseq [tv tst-vars]
      (tv))))
```

We can run our driver which will call all of our tests in `tst.demo.core`:

```
> lein run -m demo.tst
(pi) => 3.14
((var pi)) => 3.14

(ns-interns (quote tst.demo.core)) => {t1 #'tst.demo.core/t1, t2 #'tst.demo.core/t2}

tst-vars => (#'tst.demo.core/t1 #'tst.demo.core/t2)

test t1
test t2
```

## How It Works:

We digress a bit to discuss the Clojure `var`. The `var` is like a pointer from a symbol like `pi` to the function that prints `3.14`. Normally we don't even realize the `var` is there, as with the first printout:

```
(pi) => 3.14
```

We invoked the `pi` function, which returned the value 3.14, as usual.

However, we can get a reference to the `var` for the `pi` function using the wither `#'pi` or `(var pi)`.  We then invoke the `pi` function using the var, not the symbol `pi`. We see:

```
((var pi)) => 3.14
```

We use the `ns-interns` to get a map from symbols to vars in the `tst.demo.core` namespace (note: it is **critical** that we have `:require [tst.demo.core ...]` at the top of the file in the `ns` form). We printout this map:

```
(ns-interns (quote tst.demo.core)) => {t1 #'tst.demo.core/t1, t2 #'tst.demo.core/t2}
```

We only need the vars themselves, so we grab them and save into `tst-vars`:

```
tst-vars => (#'tst.demo.core/t1 #'tst.demo.core/t2)
```

Note that each `(dotest ...)` form in the testing ns `tst.demo.core` creates a *function* that is invoked during `lein test`.  We can invoke these functions ourselves, using the vars we just retrieved. This is what the `doseq` loop does, and we see the output of our mock test functions `t1` and `t2`:

```
test t1
test t2
```

The final step is to designate `demo.tst` as the main ns in `project.clj` via

```
:main demo.tst
```

which should allow you to create a uberjar and run it:

```
> java  -jar  target/uberjar/demo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar             
(pi) => 3.14
((var pi)) => 3.14
(ns-interns (quote tst.demo.core)) => {t1 #'tst.demo.core/t1, t2 #'tst.demo.core/t2}
tst-vars => (#'tst.demo.core/t1 #'tst.demo.core/t2)
test t1
test t2
```